# Let G be a finite group and N$\lhd$G such as p||N| (p dividing the order of N). Then for all P p-sylow subgroup of G, N$\cap$P$\ne{e}$

Tags: finite-groups, sylow-theory

Decide whether the following staement is true of false If true, prove it. If false, provide a counterexample

Let G be a finite group and N$\lhd$G such as p||N| (p dividing the order of N). Then for all P p-sylow subgroup of G, N$\cap$P$\ne{e}$

I think it's false but I don't know how to prove it.. 
please help :)

Comment: You really need to stop using the same title for all of your questions.

Comment: Consider the image of $P$ under the projection map $G\to G/N$.

Comment: The sentence "I think it's false but I don't know how to prove it.. please help :)" is your only contribution to this. Sorry but this is not enough. VTC.

Comment: I wrote this here because I need help not because I already found an example, I tried to found one before I wrote this here but the one I thought about didn't match every part of the question. You don't have to help me it's your decision but I'd be happy to get help from others that can and want to help

Answer (score 0):

Let $p, q$ be distinct  prime numbers. Consider $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$, $N=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$ and $P=0\times\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Your $P$ is not a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Comment: how do I prove that N is normal and that P is p-sylow? 
and what is the order of N? does p dividing this order?

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide hi can you explain to me why $N\lhd G$?